# CarrierWave Image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have a model that has:

```
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

When uploading an Image I want to retrieve some width, height and some EXIF data from the image. In a before filter I am calling `self.image.url` but this will return something like:

/uploads/tmp/20110630-1316-10507-7899/emerica_wildinthestreets.jpg

The problem is that when I try to open this image using:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.image.url)
```

I get **"No such file or directory - /uploads/tmp/20110630-1312-10507-6638/emerica_wildinthestreets.jpg"**. It seems like the image has already been moved from the tmp folder to it's final location but `self.image.url` is not reflecting this change.

I've also tried this in an `after_save` method but the result is the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I needed to append "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/" to `self.image.url`